# Proof the theorem $\int_0^\infty {{t^n}f(t)dt = {{( - 1)}^{n + 1}}\int_0^\infty {{F^{(n + 1)}}(u)du} } $

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform

> Knowing that:
> $$ L\left[ {\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{f(t)}}{t}dt} } \right] = \frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty  {F(u)du}$$
>
> with: $L[f(t)] = F(s) $
>
> Show that:
> $$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{f(t)}}{t}dt = \int_0^\infty  {F(u)du} } $$
>
> and apply it to computing:
> $$\int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sin u}}{u}du}$$
>
> Show that:
> $$\int_0^\infty  {{t^n}f(t)dt = {{( - 1)}^{n + 1}}\int_0^\infty {F^{(n + 1)}}(u)du}$$
>
> Derivative:
> $${{\rm{F}}^{(n + 1)}}(u)$$

Comment: This problem is about Laplace Transform and its inverse. Go to any DE texts to get the answer.

Comment: "Please put some work into formulating your question. Please do not just copy and paste the exact question text from your homework sheet. In particular, when you are asking for help, writing in imperative mode ('Show that...', 'Compute...', or 'Prove or find a counterexample: ...') is at the very least impolite: you are, after all, trying to ask a question, not give an assignment. It also turns many people off." (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)